# High resolution Venn diagram in r for publication

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am trying to create high resolution Venn diagram for publication. The journal requires that each figure should be uploaded as a separate file in .TIF, .JPG, or .EPS format and at sufficient resolution of at least 300 dpi at 5 in. I ran the script (below) that should create a TIFF file that is 300 DPI, 5 inches by 5 inches. Surprisingly, when I view each image in Preview on my Mac it indicates that the resolution is only 72 DPI even though the file is 9MB. I have been struggling with this conundrum for a while and hope you will be able to help.

```
library(venneuler)

library(rJava)

tiff("Figure1_sWHI.tif", res=300, compression = "lzw", height=5, width=5, units="in")

v = venneuler(c(A=16, B=16, C=16, 'A&B'=4, 'A&C'=5, 'B&C'=2, 'A&B&C'=1))
v$labels <- c("Comorbidity**", "Disability*", "Frailty***") 
plot(v)

text(.50,.52,"6.8%", cex=.8)
text(.50,.49,"n=13", cex=.7)

text(.47,.6,"n=2", cex=.8)
text(.47,.63,"1%", cex=.8)

text(.63,.48,"59%", cex=.8)
text(.63,.45,"n=112", cex=.8)

text(.63,.7,"33%", cex=.8)
text(.63,.67,"n=63", cex=.8)

text(.50,.25,"n=1147", cex=.8)

text(.4,.45,"n=30", cex=.8)

text(.3,.63,"n=19", cex=.8)

dev.off()
```

Comment: I get the same results. Importantly, the correct number of pixels are being written to the file. It just appears that the resolution metadata is not being written to the file. The image will be large enough to print, and I suspect that the publisher will be able to use them with no problems. You could manually correct the resolution in Preview by unchecking "Resample image" and then setting the Resolution to 300.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Everything worked like a magic. I resized the image and sent it to the journal.